# how to convert dataframe into time series using R

Tags: r, time-series

```
                         f1                      f2                 
1                        11/1/16                0
2                         12/1/16               0
3                         11/2/16           56.25
4                         12/2/16               0
5                         11/3/16           56.25
6                         12/3/16               0
7                         11/4/16             111
8                         12/4/16               0
9                         11/5/16               0
10                        12/5/16              13
11                        11/6/16               0
12                        12/6/16               0
13                        11/7/16               0
14                        12/7/16               0
15                        10/8/16               0
16                        11/8/16              35
17                        12/8/16               0
18                        10/9/16               0
19                        11/9/16          415.21
20                        12/9/16               0
21                       10/10/16               0
22                       11/10/16             280
23                       12/10/16             817
24                       10/11/16             830
25                       11/11/16             644
26                       12/11/16               0
27                       10/12/16               0
28                       11/12/16              90
29                       12/12/16               0
30                         1/1/17               0
31                         2/1/17             250
32                         2/1/17               0
33                         3/1/17              45
34                         3/1/17             184
35                         4/1/17          578.16
36                         4/1/17             160
37                         5/1/17              21
38                         5/1/17               0
39                         6/1/17             352
40                         6/1/17               0
41                         6/1/17            2089
42                         7/1/17               0
43                         7/1/17               0
44                         7/1/17             855
45                         8/1/17             488
46                         8/1/17             573
47                         8/1/17             654
48                         9/1/17               0
49                         9/1/17               0
50                         9/1/17            1995
51                        10/1/17               0
52                        10/1/17               0
53                        10/1/17               0
54                        11/1/17               0
55                        11/1/17             115
56                        11/1/17            2147
57                        12/1/17              74
58                        12/1/17               0
59                        12/1/17            1431
60                         1/2/17              50
```

given above dataset how this dataset can be converted into time series data like shown below which is shown below as to get the values for month the values are added for the same month.

```
       Jan            Feb   March    April   May  June  July  August  Sep      Oct   Nov    Dec
2016   0             56.25   56.25     111     13    0     0     35       415.21   1097  1474  90
2017  12011.16    50       0           0       0     0     0      0           0      0       0    0
```

i have used ts function but don'nt know how can i find the sum and arrange in proper format.

```
dat =  ts(data, start=c(2016,1), end=c(2017,1), frequency=12)
```

Comment: And how were those time series calculated? Is it `sum`? It's hard to tell as first table is 2016, 2017 while wanted result is 1950s.

Comment: This is a preloaded dataset in R environment.Name of the dataset is AirPassengers which is already in Time series format.If suppose it is a sum then how can we do it.

Comment: Please give an easy to paste reproducible example and what the output of that example would look like. Additionally, show what you've tried so far.

Comment: i have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `lubridate`.

```
dat %>%
  mutate(f1 = as.POSIXct(dat$f1, format = '%d/%m/%Y')) %>%
  mutate(month = month.abb[month(f1)], year = year(f1)) %>%
  group_by(month, year) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(f2)) %>% 
  spread(month, sum, fill = 0) %>%
  select(year, month.abb)

# # A tibble: 2 x 13
#    year    Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1   16.     0.  56.2  56.2  111.   13.    0.    0.   35.  415. 1097. 1474.   90.
# 2   17. 12011.  50.0   0.     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
```

---

#### Data

```
dat <- structure(list(f1 = c("11/1/16", "12/1/16", "11/2/16", "12/2/16", 
"11/3/16", "12/3/16", "11/4/16", "12/4/16", "11/5/16", "12/5/16", 
"11/6/16", "12/6/16", "11/7/16", "12/7/16", "10/8/16", "11/8/16", 
"12/8/16", "10/9/16", "11/9/16", "12/9/16", "10/10/16", "11/10/16", 
"12/10/16", "10/11/16", "11/11/16", "12/11/16", "10/12/16", "11/12/16", 
"12/12/16", "1/1/17", "2/1/17", "2/1/17", "3/1/17", "3/1/17", 
"4/1/17", "4/1/17", "5/1/17", "5/1/17", "6/1/17", "6/1/17", "6/1/17", 
"7/1/17", "7/1/17", "7/1/17", "8/1/17", "8/1/17", "8/1/17", "9/1/17", 
"9/1/17", "9/1/17", "10/1/17", "10/1/17", "10/1/17", "11/1/17", 
"11/1/17", "11/1/17", "12/1/17", "12/1/17", "12/1/17", "1/2/17"
), f2 = c(0, 0, 56.25, 0, 56.25, 0, 111, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 35, 0, 0, 415.21, 0, 0, 280, 817, 830, 644, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 
250, 0, 45, 184, 578.16, 160, 21, 0, 352, 0, 2089, 0, 0, 855, 
488, 573, 654, 0, 0, 1995, 0, 0, 0, 0, 115, 2147, 74, 0, 1431, 
50)), .Names = c("f1", "f2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-60L))
```

---

### Edit

To convert into a time series, you can do:

```
dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(f1 = as.POSIXct(dat$f1, format = '%d/%m/%Y')) %>%
  mutate(month = month.abb[month(f1)], year = year(f1)) %>%
  group_by(month, year) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(f2)) %>% 
  spread(month, sum, fill = 0) %>%
  select(year, month.abb) %>%
  select(-year) %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  as.vector() 
dat.ts <- ts(dat2, start = c(2016, 1), frequency = 12) 
dat.ts
```

Comment: what is <dbl> representing here

Comment: how can we convert data in time series data